# A continuous action of a compact topological group on a Hausdorff space is proper

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups, group-actions, topological-groups

**Definition:** G : topological group. A  continuous action $\alpha : G \times M \rightarrow M$ is
called a proper action if the following map is proper:

$(\alpha; \text{id}) : G \times M \rightarrow M \times M: (g; m) \mapsto (\alpha(g, m), m) $

**Suppose that $G$ is compact and $M$ is Hausdorff. I am trying to prove that a continuous
action of $G$ on $M$ is proper.**

where

**Definition:** Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map. $X,Y$ Topological spaces. $f$ is called proper if $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for every compact $K \subseteq Y$.

and the following proposition might be useful

**Proposition: If $Y$ is a metric space and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and proper, $f$ is closed**

**My try:** Let $A:=(\alpha,id)$ and $C$ be compact in $M\times M$ I want to prove that $A^{-1}(C)$ is compact. Because $C$ is compact in $M\times M$ that is Hausdorff, then $C$ is closed there and   by continuity of $A$, $A^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $G \times M$ .I am stuck here maybe if I can construct  some compact set where this last set is included I could use that a closed set in a  compact space is compact.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @user10354138 $pr_2:M \times M \rightarrow M$ and $ A: G \times M \rightarrow M \times M$, I think it's $id_{G \times M}$

Comment: @user10354138 Yeah sorry I updated my comment . I think $id_M$ means that the the domain ins M which is not the case

Comment: @user10354138 Still I don't see how to get that inclusion, surely $A^{-1}\subseteq G \times M$ but I am not very sure how to get the one you wrote

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg. It's similar but I have the same doubt about the inclusion that was left unanswered in the comments

Comment: I also would like to know how come the explicit formula of the group action is not used. Why am I given the formula then?

Comment: Consider $(m_1, m_2)\in C$. Then $A^{-1}(m_1, m_2)=(U, m_2)\subseteq A^{-1}(C)$ for some set $U\subseteq G$. So, given any $(g, m) \in A^{-1}(C),$ clearly $m \in \text{pr}_2(C)$.

Comment: @some_math_guy The inclusion is trivial to verify. I have added it there. This here is a duplicate and will probably be closed as such.